# Converting CIB data to Google Tiles with GDAL

Tags: gdal

I'm trying to convert CIB map data into Google compatible Tiles through the following process (in Linux, GDAL compiled from source):

```
gdalbuildvrt data.vrt A.TOC
gdal_translate -of VRT -expand rgba data.vrt data2.vrt
mkdir data
gdal2tiles.py data2.vrt data
```

gdal2tiles.py gives the following error:

> Generating Base Tiles: ERROR 1:
>   VRTSourcedRasterBand::IRasterIO()
>   called recursively on the same band.
>   It looks like the VRT is refe
>   rencing itself. ERROR 1: IReadBlock
>   failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0 ERROR
>   1: VRTSourcedRasterBand::IRasterIO()
>   called recursively on the same band.
>   It looks like the VRT is refe
>   rencing itself. ERROR 1: IReadBlock
>   failed at X offset 0, Y offset 0
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/local/bin/gdal2tiles.py",
>   line 2241, in ?
>       gdal2tiles.process()   File "/usr/local/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line
>   478, in process
>       self.generate_base_tiles()   File "/usr/local/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line
>   1276, in generate_base_tiles
>       dsquery.WriteRaster(wx, wy, wxsize, wysize, data,
>   band_list=list(range(1,self.dataBandsCount+1)))   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/GDAL-1.8.0-py2.4-linux-i686.egg/osgeo/gdal.py",
>   line 746, in WriteRa
>   ster
>       buf_pixel_space, buf_line_space, buf_band_space ) TypeError: not a
>   string

I know my CIB data source is valid, am I missing an obvious step?  Is this a user error or a bug in the GDAL software?  Thanks so much for any help/opinions.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a restriction on including VRTs within another VRT because it'll complicate the parsing code, I'm sure I read it on the gdal-dev mailing list, but I can't find the post at the moment. But one solution is that you can dispense with the first gdalbuildvrt and use gdal_translate directly:

```
gdal_translate -of VRT -b 1 -b 1 -b 1 A.TOC data.vrt
```

Which will duplicate all your sources for each band. I've tried this with a single GeoTIFF, and not with CIB data, but AFAIK the A.TOC file can be considered a single raster from a GDAL point of view.